# Django admin throws TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)

Tags: django-models, django-admin, typeerror

I'm working on a Python/Django application that consists of a number of models. With most of these models there are no problems, but one model causes the Django admin site to generate a 'TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type tuple)' when I want to open an instance of that model (or create a new one).

The model:

```
class Stop(models.Model):
    """
    A stop defines a station on the route of a train.
    """
    stop_id                  = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
    vehicle_id               = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    station_id               = models.ForeignKey(Station, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    platform_name            = models.IntegerField()
    platform_normal          = models.IntegerField()
    time                     = models.DateTimeField()
    delay                    = models.IntegerField()
    scheduled_arrival_time   = models.DateTimeField()
    arrival_delay            = models.IntegerField()
    arrival_cancelled        = models.IntegerField()
    arrived                  = models.IntegerField()
    scheduled_departure_time = models.DateTimeField()
    departure_delay          = models.IntegerField()
    departure_cancelled      = models.IntegerField()
    left                     = models.IntegerField()
    cancelled                = models.IntegerField()
    is_extra_stop            = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        """
        String representation of the stop.
        """
        return_string = f"{self.stop_id} - {self.time}"
        return return_string
```

(I've aligned the field specifications for clarity here)

I don't have a problem with populating the model. I also do get a list of the instances in the model, but when I want to view an instance, I get the TypeError.

[Admin overview of the Stop model instances](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odHQ1.png)

I tried different definitions of the **str**(self) method, but the result remained the same.
Also found no answer to this specific problem on stackoverflow or any other web resource.

Comment: please add error details scrrenshot

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

It turns out that the `__str__()` method of the Vehicle class, to which the Stop class refers `(vehicle_id = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` returns a tuple, i.e. `return self.station_id, self.standard_name`.
Changing this to return `self.standard_name` solved the problem.